# How to escape backslash in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace backslash => '\' with secure `&#92;` replacement.

But my code replacing all '#' fails when applied for replacing '\':

```
el = el.replace(/\#/g, '&#35;'); // replaces all '#' //that's cool
el = el.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;'); // replaces all '\' //that's failing
```

Why?

Comment: The code you posted works just fine. Are you sure that `el` contains `'\'` characters?

Comment: Can you give us a test case where it is failing, seems to work for me on a simple test case.

Comment: Hmm take a look: http://pastebin.com/t27vmCzs

Comment: In that script you already use encodeURIComponent() which replaces any backslashes with %5C. I think you don't need the two manual replacements.

Comment: FYI `#` doesn't need to be escaped; `el.replace(/#/g, '&#35;')` should work. And also your code to replace backslashes works fine here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

open console and type

```
'\'.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;');
```

fails because the slash in the string isn't really in the string, it's escaping '

```
'\\'.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;');
```

works because it takes one slash and finds it.

your regex works.

Comment: so how do you handle "domain\user" then? you got to first replace single backslash to double and then use .replace(/\\/g, '&#92;'); ?

Comment: `/\\/g` looks for a single backslash.  At no point are we replacing a single with a double.  The first backslash escapes the second one, so this regex looks for a single backslash, globally.  to handle "domain\user", `/\\/g` should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.raw](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) to add slashes conveniently into your string literals. E.g. `` String.raw`\a\bcd\e`.replace(/\\/g, '&#92;'); ``